# Snowflake & GoodData Error "All Projects Failed to Load"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, gooddata

I’ve connected Snowflake’s test data to GoodData, added the model and tried to load the data but getting an error that says “All Projects Failed to Load” every time I try to load the data.

Here is the error code:

```
2021-02-26T17:33:08.304+0100 [ERROR]: Fail to load projects "[clr5mf5skkcnvxg3nez8a5zevd9urahu]". Reason: Unable to unload:    StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE  STAGE__20210226__GhFKNxK2  COPY_OPTIONS = ( on_error='skip_file' )]; nested exception is net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL execution error: Creating stage on shared database 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA' is not allowed.:    SQL execution error: Creating stage on shared database 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA' is not allowed.2021-02-26T17:33:08.310+0100 [INFO]: ====================== End of downloading and integrating data ======================2021-02-26T17:33:08.311+0100 [ERROR]: Data distribution worker failed. Reason: All projects failed to load.
```

Has anyone experienced that and was able to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant part of the error message:

```
Creating stage on shared database 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA' is not allowed.
```

You'll want to set the context in your session to another database. SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA is a shared database, which is read only.

You can do this to set the context before running that statement:

```
use database MY_DATABASE;
```

Or you could specify the database for the stage in the statement itself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE
MY_DATABASE.MY_SCHEMA.STAGE__20210226__GhFKNxK2
COPY_OPTIONS = ( on_error='skip_file' );
```

Answer (score -1):

In snowflake integration with GoodData the data in output staging is downloaded to CSV files and then they're uploaded to GoodData staging area. As part of this process below statement is run in snowflake database according to error log:

`CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE  STAGE__20210226__GhFKNxK2  COPY_OPTIONS = ( on_error='skip_file' )`

However, it failed with

`Creating stage on shared database 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA' is not allowed.:    SQL execution error: Creating stage on shared database 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA' is not allowed`

So this issue could be related to your user's permissions on the snowflake DB SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA. Please set up your user ROLE's permissions according to guide:

[GoodData-Snowflake Integration Details](https://help.gooddata.com/doc/en/data-integration/data-preparation-and-distribution/direct-data-distribution-from-data-warehouses-and-object-storage-services/gooddata-snowflake-integration-details)

You seem to be missing below permission in your user's ROLE, please be sure to have added this permission in snowflake DB.

GRANT CREATE STAGE ON SCHEMA {database_name}.{schema_name} TO ROLE {role_name};